# How do I upgrade to iOS 9.3 without enabling iCloud Drive?

Tags: ipad, icloud, ios

I am (or rather, my brother-in-law is) trying to update the OS on an older iPad, and he's adamant that we need to do this without signing up/enabling/whatever it is that you do with iCloud Drive. So now we're presented with the following question:

> **Are you sure you don't want to upgrade to iCloud Drive?**
>   iOS 9 requires upgrading to iCloud Drive to update documents in iCloud. Until you upgrade, changes made to documents on this iPad will not be available to other devices using iCloud.
>   **Cancel**   Continue

Uh... mu? Neither of those is a valid answer to the question. What does "Continue" mean? Why is "Cancel" highlighted? Besides forwarding this to the Interface Hall of Shame, what the heck am I supposed to do here? **How do I answer this question in such a way that I will not get iCloud Drive foisted on me?**

Answer (score 2):

The brother-in-law resorted to a chat session with Apple support, and after wading through a lot of boilerplate, he was advised to choose "Continue". It seems to have worked. He did not, however, get any answer to how such a textbook example of how *not* to write a dialog box got past Apple's UI designers.

Answer (score 0):

Select cancel, then select that you'll decide later and continue with the process. You do not need to enable iCloud Drive for any updates to use the device.